# Open iTune link from the application for some music selected by user in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

I am facing issue to open iTunes link from my application to iTunes in iOS 7.0

Below is the complete url generate into the application

```
NSString* urlStr = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?partnerId=30&siteID=2htbGpeyFlc&term=Citizen%20Cope%20Bullet%20and%20a%20Target";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr2]];
```

When I am open it below iOS 7.0 then its working fine and open iTunes and search the playlist "Citizen Cope Bullet and a Target" and its working fine upto iOS 6.0.

But its not working for the iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to open a string named "`urlStr2`" while you've *really* put your URL into a *different* NSString object named "`urlStr`".

Unless you missed copying & pasting some lines of code in your question.

Comment: its urlStr in place of urlStr2. ANd I have got the solution for it.
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?partnerId=30&siteID=2htbGpeyFlc&term=
should be replace with below and its working fine for me in iOS 7.0, 6.0, 5.0
http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?partnerId=30&siteID=2htbGpeyFlc&term="